# Bitlocker is not asking for password after altering bcd

Tags: boot, bitlocker, password-protection, bcd, bcdedit

I'm using Windows Server so I needed to disable Hyper-V for using VMWare Workstation. I altered bcd to set "hypervisorlaunchtype off" and now Bitlocker is not asking for a password. I also tried to backup original bcd but no chance.

Side note: There's nothing with TPM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Can you provide the status of BitLocker using the appropriate command